# Update to angular2 release candidate

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I cannot find the `RouteConfig` the angular website it says that it is in the @angular/router but there is no export for the RouteConfig, does anyone know if this is a bug ?

Answer (score 0):

i think if you still want to use the "old" RouteConfig you should import
'@angular/router-deprecated'

The docs are updated and it seems like you would configure your routes now this way: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-config
Try it out or get the router-deprecated.
I think the docs are still getting updated...